# Installing a personal security certificate for Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services user

Tags: windows, windows-terminal-services, certificate

We use StoneEdge Order Manager, which runs under Microsoft Access, on several Windows computers as well as through Terminal Services on Windows Server 2008. Terminal Services users are unable to process credit cards using the First Data Global Gateway on the server. We have followed the necessary setup instructions provided under the user account, which involves adding a certificate in the Internet Options control panel. The Windows XP desktops require this to be done, or a generic 'unable to connect' message is shown when attempting to charge a card. On the server, this message is shown regardless of whether the certificate has been installed. Is there anything else that needs to be done that is specific to Windows Server that is not mentioned in the workstation instructions?

[Setup Instructions](http://www.stoneedge.com/help/mergedProjects/3rdparty/First_Data_Global_Gateway_Virtual_Terminal_(formerly_LinkPoint).htm)

Comment: Are the terminal servers using mandatory profiles?